# .onRecieve in swift not working as described

Tags: swiftui

```
@EnvironmentObject var v: Variables


if !isActiveView {
 VStack {

}    
 .onReceive(v.$AllAirplanes) { plane in
          if plane != [] {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
              withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 1.0)) {
                isAnimation.toggle()
              }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.8) {
              withAnimation {
                isActiveView.toggle()
                locationViewModel.getUserLocation()
              }
            }
          }
        }
}
```

This is my code. I am getting v.$AllAirplanes from firebase and trying to get my loading screen to keep going until the variable does not equal []. The problem is that it only tests once, so I'm forever stuck on the loading screen, even if the value changes.

From what I've read, I thought OnReceive was how, and the best way to do this. Should I go about this another way?

Edit: I'm updating v.AllAirplanes with this function -

```
@StateObject var v = Variables()


  func getAllAirplanes() {
    db.collection("Airplanes")
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
          guard (querySnapshot?.documents) != nil else {
                print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            v.AllAirplanes.removeAll()
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
              print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
              //GET DATA AND SET TO VARIABLE
              v.AllAirplanes.append(document.documentID)
            }
          v.AllAirplanes.remove(object: "Simulator")
          //v.AllAirplanes.append("-Please select an airplane-")
print(
"""
------------------------------
All Airplanes: \(v.AllAirplanes)
------------------------------
"""
)
        }
  }
```

and this is my class -

```
class Variables: ObservableObject {
    @Published var AllAirplanes: String<Array> = []
}
```

Comment: Show us how you are updating `AllAirplanes`

Comment: In your `class Variables:`, have you tried using `@Published var AllAirplanes: [String] = []` instead of `String<Array>`

Comment: Generally, you want to store a reference to the listener returned by `addSnapshotListener`. You're not showing where this function lives, but it should likely be in an `ObservableObject` and not in a `View`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my test example code that shows `.onRecieve` working as expected.

```
class Variables: ObservableObject {
    @Published var AllAirplanes: [String] = ["1","2","3"]
}

struct TestingView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var v: Variables
    
    @State var isActiveView = false
    @State var isAnimation = false
    
    var body: some View {
        // for testing, wait 2 secs then click the button
        Button(action: {
            // change AllAirplanes 
            v.AllAirplanes.append(UUID().uuidString)
            isActiveView.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Test change AllAirplanes (wait 2 seconds first)")
        }
        
        if !isActiveView {
            VStack {
                Text("TestingView")
            }
            .onReceive(v.$AllAirplanes) { plane in
                print("-----> in onReceive plane: \(plane)")
                if plane != [] {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                        withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 1.0)) {
                            isAnimation.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                        withAnimation {
                            isActiveView.toggle()
                            //  locationViewModel.getUserLocation()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var v = Variables()
    
    var body: some View {
        TestingView().environmentObject(v)
    }
}
```

Comment: Two questions. 1) Is it better to use [String]? 2) Maybe my problem is not adding .environmentObject(v) to TestingView()? What does that do? Right now I only have that under my SceneDelegate for ContentView().

Comment: its weird, because if you uncomment the line "//v.AllAirplanes.append("-Please select an airplane-")", it works perfectly fine. Any idea why?

Comment: `String<Array>` does not make sense, use `[String]` to represent an array of Strings.
You must use `.environmentObject(v)` to pass `v` to `TestingView` (there are other ways). For some good explanations of how to use `ObservableObject` and how to pass them around, see: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app 

`v.AllAirplanes.append(UUID().uuidString)` is used for testing, to change/add to `v.AllAirplanes` 
so that the `.onReceive` is triggered.

If my answer helped, could you mark it as accepted, using the tick mark, it turns green.

Comment: Any idea about my comment above?

Comment: Adding `v.AllAirplanes.append("-Please select an airplane-")`, after
 `v.AllAirplanes.append(UUID().uuidString)` or instead of it, works well in my code.

Comment: But if I remove that, and just use the firebase data. Then, it doesn't work.

Comment: UPDATE: It was actually the v.AllAirplanes.remove(object: "Simulator")

Comment: Glad it worked.  Typically in an array of Strings, you would use
  `v.AllAirplanes.removeAll(where: {$0 == "Simulator"})`